# Problems with React native's tintColor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-animated

I am very new to React Native and have come across a problem which occurs when I want to animate an images tint color. I expect the color to change gradually over time like Animated.Timing should achieve, but instead it only does the first frame of the animation then freezes. However, for some reason when I just change 'tintColor' to 'backgroundColor' the animation works fine.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableHighlight, Dimensions, Component, Image, Animated } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function RGBtoCSS(rgb) {
    return "rgb(" + rgb[0] + "," + rgb[1] + "," + rgb[2] + ")";
}

class MyImage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.anim = new Animated.Value(0);
        this.animate();
    }

    animate() {
        this.props.onPress();

        Animated.timing(
            this.anim,
            {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: false
            }
        ).start();
    }

    render() {
        var style = {
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            resizeMode: 'stretch'
        };

        var col = this.anim.interpolate(
        {
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [RGBtoCSS([0, 0, 0]), RGBtoCSS([140, 74, 140])]
        });

        return (
            <Animated.Image source={this.props.img} style={{ ...style, tintColor: col }} />
        );
    }
}
MyImage.propTypes = { img: PropTypes.string.isRequired, onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired, spacing: PropTypes.number.isRequired };

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: RGBtoCSS([255, 255, 255])
        }}>
            <MyImage img={{ uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/452/google-logo.png' }} onPress={() => { }} spacing={0} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

(demo available at https://snack.expo.dev/v0GeiLbOP)

Comment: Seems like `tintColor` is not animatable.

Comment: is there an animatable alternative?

Comment: did you try to log the `RGBtoCSS` function to see which values are calculated? It could be that `interpolate` does not work well with your function.

Comment: it works fine with backgroundColor, so i don't think its the problem

Comment: and ive already tried that

Comment: if tintColor is not animatable you could inverse the image and use backgroundColor. Probably not what you want, but at least an option. Or you create a custom component...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i will use that for now

Comment: is there a stylesheet field that automates that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. You can stack two `<Animated.Image>` on top of each other, with 1st Image being of final color, and 2nd image being of starting color. Then you can use `opacity` to create a fading effect, between these two Images, which also works well with `interpolate`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableHighlight, Dimensions, Component, Image, Animated } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function RGBtoCSS(rgb) {
    return "rgb(" + rgb[0] + "," + rgb[1] + "," + rgb[2] +")";
}

class MyImage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.anim = new Animated.Value(0);
        this.animate();
    }

    animate() {
        this.props.onPress();
        console.log(this.anim)

        Animated.timing(
            this.anim,
            {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: false
            }
        ).start();
    }

    render() {
        var style = {
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            resizeMode: 'stretch'
        };

        var col = this.anim.interpolate(
        {
            inputRange: [0, 1], 
            outputRange: [1, 0]
        });


    
        return (
          <View>
            <Animated.Image source={this.props.img} style={{ ...style,tintColor: RGBtoCSS([140, 74, 140]) }} />
            <Animated.Image source={this.props.img} style={{ ...style, opacity:col, transform:[{translateY:"-100%"}],  tintColor: RGBtoCSS([0, 0, 0]) }} />
            </View>
        );
    }

}
MyImage.propTypes = { img: PropTypes.string.isRequired, onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired, spacing: PropTypes.number.isRequired };

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: RGBtoCSS([255, 255, 255])
        }}>
            <MyImage img={{ uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/452/google-logo.png' }} onPress={() => { }} spacing={0} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Snack - https://snack.expo.dev/ZYulbKh3g